# Could not resolve paths sonarscan and bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, sonarscanner

I'm trying to configure CI on my project.

Here, is the bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
clone:
    depth: full

pipelines:
    branches:
        '{master}':
            - step:
                  name: Tests PHPUnit
                  services:
                      - docker
                  caches:
                      - docker
                  script:
                      - curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
                      - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
                      - cd scripts
                      - sh smf_recreate.sh
                      - sh smf_init.sh
                      - sh smf_tests.sh
                  artifacts:
                      - back/test-reports/**
                      - back/src/**
                      - back/tests/**
            - step:
                  name: Analyse SonarQube
                  image: maven:3.8.1
                  caches:
                      - sonar
                  script:
                      - mkdir -p /usr/src/app/
                      - mv back/src/ /usr/src/app/
                      - mv back/tests/ /usr/src/app/
                      - pipe: sonarsource/sonarqube-scan:1.0.0
                        variables:
                            SONAR_HOST_URL: ${SONAR_HOST_URL}
                            SONAR_TOKEN: ${SONAR_TOKEN}

definitions:
    caches:
        sonar: ~/.sonar
```

The first step creates a docker container, which makes PHPUnit test, and exports the test-reports (artifacts) to the next step.

The result-coverage.xml look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage generated="1629298870">
  <project timestamp="1629298870">
    <file name="/usr/src/app/src/Controller/TempController.php">
      <class name="App\Controller\TempController" namespace="global">
        <metrics complexity="0" methods="0" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="0" coveredstatements="0" elements="0" coveredelements="0"/>
      </class>
      <metrics loc="15" ncloc="10" classes="0" methods="0" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="0" coveredstatements="0" elements="0" coveredelements="0"/>
    </file>
    <file name="/usr/src/app/src/EventListener/Listener.php">
      <class name="App\EventListener\Listener" namespace="global">
        <metrics complexity="9" methods="6" coveredmethods="6" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="23" coveredstatements="23" elements="29" coveredelements="29"/>
      </class>
      <line num="32" type="method" name="__construct" visibility="public" complexity="1" crap="1" count="4"/>
      <line num="34" type="stmt" count="4"/>
      <line num="35" type="stmt" count="4"/>
      <line num="43" type="method" name="prePersist" visibility="public" complexity="1" crap="1" count="1"/>
      <line num="46" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="47" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="48" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="56" type="method" name="postPersist" visibility="public" complexity="1" crap="1" count="1"/>
      <line num="58" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="66" type="method" name="preUpdate" visibility="public" complexity="1" crap="1" count="1"/>
      <line num="68" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="69" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="76" type="method" name="postUpdate" visibility="public" complexity="1" crap="1" count="1"/>
      <line num="78" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="79" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="80" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="82" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="91" type="method" name="history" visibility="private" complexity="4" crap="4" count="2"/>
      <line num="93" type="stmt" count="2"/>
      <line num="94" type="stmt" count="2"/>
      <line num="95" type="stmt" count="2"/>
      <line num="97" type="stmt" count="2"/>
      <line num="100" type="stmt" count="2"/>
      <line num="101" type="stmt" count="2"/>
      <line num="102" type="stmt" count="2"/>
      <line num="103" type="stmt" count="2"/>
      <line num="104" type="stmt" count="2"/>
      <line num="106" type="stmt" count="2"/>
      <line num="108" type="stmt" count="2"/>
      <metrics loc="110" ncloc="69" classes="1" methods="6" coveredmethods="6" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="23" coveredstatements="23" elements="29" coveredelements="29"/>
    </file>
    <file name="/usr/src/app/src/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php">
      <class name="App\EventListener\ExceptionListener" namespace="global">
        <metrics complexity="3" methods="2" coveredmethods="2" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="20" coveredstatements="20" elements="22" coveredelements="22"/>
      </class>
      <line num="27" type="method" name="__construct" visibility="public" complexity="1" crap="1" count="1"/>
      <line num="29" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="30" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="36" type="method" name="onKernelException" visibility="public" complexity="2" crap="2" count="1"/>
      <line num="38" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="40" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="42" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="46" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="47" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="48" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="49" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="50" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="51" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="52" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="53" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="55" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="56" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="58" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="59" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="60" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="62" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="63" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <metrics loc="65" ncloc="50" classes="1" methods="2" coveredmethods="2" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="20" coveredstatements="20" elements="22" coveredelements="22"/>
    </file>
    <metrics files="3" loc="190" ncloc="129" classes="2" methods="8" coveredmethods="8" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="43" coveredstatements="43" elements="51" coveredelements="51"/>
  </project>
</coverage>
```

As we can see, the "file" attributes starts by "/usr/src/app" which is the context of my docker container.

The problem is on the 2nd step, when Sonarscan trying to analyze the files, it can't find them because it is trying to check at /usr/src/app...

> INFO: Analyzing PHPUnit coverage report: back/test-reports/result-coverage.xml

> WARN: Could not resolve 3 file paths in result-coverage.xml, first
> unresolved path: /usr/src/app/src/Controller/TempController.php

Indeed, in the sonarscan container (2nd step), they are located at /back/src/** ...
How can I tell sonarscan to look at this directory, and not the one specified in result-coverage.xml?

Thanks!